Which parameters of the Sholl analysis summary do I need to compare to get descriptive graphs about the complexity of single neurons?
For my master thesis I am working with Purkinje cells from Zebrafish with a condition that makes these neurons less complex. I am treating them with a construct that is hypothesized to improve this condition. I analyze the images of the single neurons I take via Sholl (Fiji). My problem is that, in the end, I get summary tables with over 26 parameters, and I am not sure which ones are best to mirror the complexity of the neurons.
